# problema com validação de dados preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

olá, boa noite a todos estou com um problema no quesito de validação de formulario onde meu preg_match funciona perfeitamente porem não permite espaços alguem sabe me dizer como deixar que o usuario insira espaços entre as palavras?`if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+?$/i", $string)){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta vc adicionar um \s na sua regex, assim:

> [a-zA-Z\d\s]

Também troquei o 0-9 por \d só pra mostrar q dá pra fazer assim.

Comment: Obrigado amigo deu certo

Comment: e se eu quiser liberar tambem o caractere  ' @ ' e o ' _ ' ?

Comment: Verdade tinha esquecido do `\d` :P, value @AdrianoBack

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer assim:

```
$string = 'palavra com espaço 123';
if (preg_match("/[\sa-zA-Z0-9]+?$/i", $string)) {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($string); echo '</pre>';
}
```

Adicionando um `\s` que coincide com qualquer caractere de espaço em branco.

Comment: obrigado deu certo tambem